# What could be wrong in this body function?

Tags: python, function

I am developing a function for a game and I am getting stuck in a function that must return if a word is included in a board. Python's shell returns me a False condition when it suppose to be True.
This is my body funtion:

```
def board_contains_word(board, word):
    """ (list of list of str, str) -> bool

Return True if and only if word appears in board.
Precondition: board has at least one row and one column.

>>> board_contains_word([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'ANT')
True
"""
for word_index in range(len(board)):
    if word in board:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: `for word_index in range(len(board)):` what is the point of `word_index` because you never use it within the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop, but you're ignoring the loop counter. You set the value in each iteration into the `word_index` variable; you should use that inside your loop.

Your other issue is that you always return after the first iteration. Your second `return` should be *outside* the loop, so that it only runs if the entire loop is exhausted.

```
for word_index in range(len(board)):
    if word in board[word_index]:
        return True
return False
```

However, having said this, in Python you should pretty much never iterate through range(len(something)). Always iterate through the thing itself:

```
for word_list in board:
    if word in word_list:
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a string in a list of lists, python does not recurse in lists, and even if it did, you will still not find it, because you have a list of characters not a string:

```
def board_contains_word(board, word):
    for element in board:  # First Iterate each list in the board.
        if word in ''.join(element):  # Then join the list of characters to make a word and look for your desired word in it
            return True
    return False
```